# why 2.valueOf() is not valid but (2).valueOf() is?

Tags: javascript

I guess that javascript will parse `(2).valueOf()` to `new Number(2).valueOf()` but why it doesn't for the first one ?

According to the operator precedence, the grouping operator shall have a higher priority than the member access https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

So why `(2)` is not be evaluated first and yield `2` instead of be parsed to `new Number(2)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Because in `2.valueOf` the `.` is considered to be as a part of `2` instead of being understood as `method accessing`.

That is why `2..valueOf()` works.

```js
console.log(2..valueOf());
```

Comment: I see, I should try the `string` first before asking this question. Thanks!